# Two querys in one [MYSQL] ONE RESULTS

Tags: mysql, join

can you help me guys to join two queries in one?
This is my first query:

```
SELECT estimated_sum_all, story_point_sum_all, time_spent,  reg_date
FROM burndown_snap_all  WHERE project_id='72'
```

Results:

```
 | estimated_sum_all | story_point_sum_all | time_spent | reg_date |
 | 300               | 20                  | 20.30      | 2017-09  |
 | 300               | 20                  | 19.30      | 2017-09  |
 | 300               | 20                  | 18.30      | 2017-09  |
 | 300               | 20                  | 15.32      | 2017-09  |
```

This is my second query:

```
SELECT time_spent FROM status_history_hours where
project_id = '72'
```

Results:

```
| time_spent | 
| 20.30      |
| 20.30      |
| 20.30      |
| 20.30      |
```

What I wanna to do is to build one mysql query that have to contain select/join to  time_spent from the second query. Final table should looks like this:

```
 | estimated_sum_all | story_point_sum_all | time_spent | reg_date |
 | 300               | 20                  | 20.30      | 2017-09  |
 | 300               | 20                  | 20.30      | 2017-09  |
 | 300               | 20                  | 20.30      | 2017-09  |
 | 300               | 20                  | 20.30      | 2017-09  |
```

Regards,

Solution for this would be like:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.estimated_sum_all, 
t1.story_point_sum_all, t1.time_spent, 
t2.id, t2.time_spent FROM 
burndown_snap_all t1, status_history_hours 
t2 WHERE t1.project_id = 72 AND 
t2.project_id = 72 group by t1.id
```

But how to group by t2.id in the same time???

Comment: Perhaps you have other columns in the second table that would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT estimated_sum_all, story_point_sum_all, time_spent,  reg_date
FROM burndown_snap_all  WHERE project_id='72'
UNION ALL
SELECT time_spent FROM status_history_hours where
project_id = '72'
```

Comment: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns :)

Answer (score 1):

From the data that you have provided, you can take *any* matching value from the second table.  So, you could do:

```
SELECT bsa.estimated_sum_all, bsa.story_point_sum_all, bsa.time_spent,
       bsa.reg_date,
       (SELECT MAX(shh.time_spent)
        FROM status_history_hours shh
        WHERE shh.project_id = bsa.project_id
       ) as time_spent
FROM burndown_snap_all bsa
WHERE project_id = 72;
```

Comment: Yes but the times_spent can contain different values in the second table.

Comment: @ValeriusRomulus . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question with more appropriate sample data and an explanation of how to do the matching.  If you change this question, you will invalidate this answer, which can draw downvotes.

Comment: project_id is the only one common column for these two tables. Tables have the same number of the records. Just wanna to join only time_spent for The results.

Comment: SELECT bsa.estimated_sum_all, bsa.story_point_sum_all, bsa.time_spent, bsa.reg_date, (SELECT shh.time_spent FROM status_history_hours shh WHERE shh.project_id = bsa.project_id) as time_spent FROM burndown_snap_all bsa WHERE project_id = 72;

Would be good but this returning: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row